# Error compiling OpenMPI with ifort

Tags: compile, configure

I'm trying to compile [OpenMPI 1.10.2](https://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v1.10/) using the [Intel Fortran compiler](https://software.intel.com/en-us/qualify-for-free-software/student) (ifort) installed with graphic interface.
When configuring

```
sudo ./configure FC="ifort"
```

(as told by README to set a different compiler) I get the following error

```
    *** Fortran compiler
checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran compiler... no
checking whether ifort accepts -g... no
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking if Fortran compiler works... no
**********************************************************************
* It appears that your Fortran compiler is unable to produce working
* executables.  A simple test application failed to properly
* execute.  Note that this is likely not a problem with Open MPI,
* but a problem with the local compiler installation.  More
* information (including exactly what command was given to the
* compiler and what error resulted when the command was executed) is
* available in the config.log file in the Open MPI build directory.
**********************************************************************
configure: error: Could not run a simple Fortran program.  Aborting.
```

Looking in the *config.log* file I read this:

```
 configure:32556: checking if Fortran compiler works
configure:32585: ifort -o conftest /opt/intel/bin/   conftest.f  >&5
./configure: line 4835: ifort: command not found
configure:32585: $? = 127
configure: program exited with status 127
configure: failed program was:
|       program main
| 
|       end
configure:32601: result: no
configure:32615: error: Could not run a simple Fortran program.  Aborting.
```

So I tried running ifort alone, and it works.
Also, I can't find the *conftest.f* file.

Same issues with icc (Intel c++ compiler).

I think there is some path to put in, but don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your `ifort` should be in the `PATH`.

```
export PATH=<path_to_your_ifort_binary>:$PATH
sudo ./configure FC="ifort"
```

Change `<path_to_your_ifort_binary>` to the real directory.

The other way, Intel compiler has a script file, `ifortvars.sh`, which does the work with all variables for you. Taking into account that  is a directory where Intel Compiler is installed, add to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
source <install-dir>/bin/ifortvars.sh intel64
```

The third way to try is to use `compilervars.sh` from Intel Composer. [Please, see here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19043082/1566267)